# MKmapview gets reset when updating location

Tags: swift

I have this code:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
    {
        let location = locations.last


            let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: (location?.coordinate.latitude)!, longitude: (location?.coordinate.longitude)!)
            let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.03, longitudeDelta: 0.03))
            self.map.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    }
```

But when I'm interacting with the map and the location is updated a little goes it back the the "center" of the current location. Is it possible to do that only the first time, and that it doesn't move the map when Im interacting with it?

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you can't just set a property and then reset it the first time you update the location?

```
var updateRegion = true


func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
    {
        let location = locations.last


            let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: (location?.coordinate.latitude)!, longitude: (location?.coordinate.longitude)!)
            let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.03, longitudeDelta: 0.03))
            if updateRegion {
               self.map.setRegion(region, animated: true)
               updateRegion = false
            }



    }
```